# Using parasitic inheritance in Javascript, is it possible to implement introspective instance methods?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to develop a simple parasitic interface for my Javascript classes modeled after [Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) and I'd like to implement some basic introspective methods. Given the classes below, how can I write `class_name` and `is_a` methods that correctly identify the object class?

```
function Parent(name) {
    var self = {};
    self.name = name;

    self.init = function() {
        console.debug('init', self);
        return self;
    };

    self.ama = function() {
        return "AMA Parent named " + self.name;
    };

    // Introspective methods
    self.class_name = function() {
        // returns class name as a string
    };

    self.is_a = function(obj_class) {
        // returns boolean indicating whether object is instance of obj_class
    };

    self = self.init();
    return self;
}

function Child(name) {  
    var self = new Parent(name);

    var base_ama = self.ama;
    self.ama = function() {
        var ama = base_ama();
        return ama + ". NOT!";
    };

    self.init();
    return self;
}
```

Here are the tests it would be expected to pass:

```
var alice = new Parent('Alice');
assert_equal(alice.name, 'Alice');
assert_equal(alice.class_name(), 'Parent');
assert(alice.is_a(Parent));
assert_not(alice.is_a(Child));
assert_equal(alice.ama(), 'AMA Parent named Alice');

var bob = new Child('Bob');
assert_equal(bob.class_name(), 'Child');
assert_not(bob.is_a(Parent));
assert(bob.is_a(Child));
assert_equal(bob.ama(), 'AMA Parent named Bob. NOT!');
```

You can find a fiddle here with tests set up:

http://jsfiddle.net/LTfVa/3/

Comment: If you didn't fight against the language so hard, you could use the already available `instanceof` and `.constructor.name` out of the box. You also get to use a keyword instead of ad hoc variable for accessing the object.

Comment: “Whoever fights monsters should see to it that in the process he does not become a monster." Javascript is turning me into a monster.

Comment: Well it's impossible to do this reliably because from language POV you are using top level Object and abusing the dynamic nature to make it sorta look like inheritance. You could encode the name and relationship manually. I still must note that javascript has perfectly good OOP mechanics that you could use to make your code more performant, maintainable and readable.

Comment: I would be happy to see a more paradigmatic approach for the example presented in the question. One thing about Crockford's approach that strongly appeals to me is the way it manages to encapsulate the class declarations in a single function. (Though he does do some voodoo with the Object prototype, which I didn't like so much.)

Comment: There's something very important in Crockford article. The very last sentence. "I now see my early attempts to support the classical model in JavaScript as a mistake." You are trying to do something that simply does not make sense in this language. There are simply no problems that require the use of this type of model to be solved elegantly in JavaScript. There are far simpler and more idiomatic solutions for whatever you're trying to achieve, I promise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototypal inheritance is performant, economical about memory, relatively simple, and idiomatic to Javascript's features. In my opinion, parasitic inheritance is none of those things:

```
// extend:
// receiverCtor - A constructor function that we want to extend with another constructor's behavior
// supplierCtor - The supplier of the other constructor's behavior
// receiverProperties - Any instance methods/properties you want to push onto the receiver's prototype
// receiverStatics - Any methods/properties you want to attach to the constructor function itself
//
function extend(receiverCtor, supplierCtor, receiverProperties, receiverStatics) {
    receiverProperties = receiverProperties || {};
    receiverStatics = receiverStatics || {};

    var supplierProto = supplierCtor.prototype,
        receiverProto = Object.create(supplierProto),
        prop;

    receiverCtor.prototype = receiverProto;
    receiverProto.constructor = receiverCtor;
    receiverCtor.parent = supplierProto;

    if(supplierCtor !== Object && supplierProto.constructo === Object.prototype.constructor) {
        supplierProto.constructor = supplierCtor;
    }

    for(prop in receiverProperties) {
        if(receiverProperties.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            receiverProto[prop] = receiverProperties[prop];
        }
    }

    for(prop in receiverStatics) {
        if(receiverStatics.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            receiverCtor[prop] = receiverStatics[prop];
        }
    }
}

function Parent(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

function Child(name) {
    Child.parent.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}

extend(Child, Parent);

var alice = new Parent('alice');
var bob = new Child('bob');

console.log(alice instanceof Parent);
console.log(!(alice instanceof Child));
console.log(alice.name == 'alice');

console.log(bob instanceof Parent); // inherits from parent
console.log(bob.constructor !== Parent); // but it isn't a parent
console.log(bob instanceof Child);
console.log(bob.constructor === Child);
console.log(bob.name === 'bob');
```

[Here's a jsbin to verify](http://jsbin.com/IJEVemO/1/edit).

EDIT: The `extend` function is a collection of syntax sugar on top of the following very simple relationship:

```
function Parent(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

function Child(name) {
    Parent.apply(this, arguments);
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

The above ten lines will pass all the tests from the first example.

Comment: An upvote the example. Now as to why this turns me off... I'd have to see some compelling benchmark data before I'd factor performance into my assessment so I'll put that aside for now. I suppose you could call this relatively simply. I find it a bit awkward. And at the point at which I have to define my own extend function, I'd be in the market for a popular lightweight framework or library that shoehorns in conventional OOP behavior for me.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the smallest seed of what the `extend` function is doing. I recommend reading these two articles on constructor/prototype chaining: [one](http://fromanegg.com/post/39621616853/constructor-chaining-inheritance-in-javascript), [two](http://fromanegg.com/post/41107863511/prototypes-and-class-like-objects-in-javascript).

Comment: The edited version looks more appealing. But is it possible to override methods without the extend function? I'm having trouble implementing that. You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/AxY7g/1/

Comment: @klenwell There is no reason to make a benchmark to be convinced that O(1) is massively better than O(N), however here is for N=25 http://jsperf.com/prtorpropr

Comment: @klenwell: You can override methods in a couple ways. I've detailed them in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZ6AH/1/). In practice, though, method overrides in JS are less useful than they appear when you can call any method against any object you want.

Comment: Bear in mind that you cannot safely access non-scalar members of privileged methods with prototypical inheritance. Parasitic constructors are a necessity if any super classes require private state, or if you will have reference types as their members (arrays, objects).